# Proof of Funds and return ticket for Schengen visa waiver - US Citizen

Tags: schengen, us-citizens, proof-provenance-of-funds

I noticed the State Department website had the following:

> Immigration officers may also request you show sufficient funds for your intended stay and a return airline ticket.

For those of you who've traveled there, in your experience is this something passport control typically asks for?

Comment: It's typically down to the person's age, gender, nationality, experience, and some intangibles.  The UK version is here http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49231/uk-immigration-officers-arrivals-interview-questions

Comment: Having visited just last month.  No.  But as @GayotFow said it depends on whether or not you personally warrant collection of such information based on the opinion of the officer.

Comment: I've never been asked, but they certainly could, especially if they think there's a reason to.

Comment: Thanks guys, so if they asked for proof of funds would I need to show them a bank statement or a credit card I intend to use there?

I will probably take a copy of my offer letter and a couple of paystubs just in case.

Comment: Whoa. Offer letter? Are you going for an interview or to start a job?

Comment: No, I have a job in the US. I'm only going for a 2 week holiday to Europe and will be visiting several countries during that 2-week period. I'm not sure what exactly constitutes a proof of funds.

Comment: Anyone still have an answer over what constitutes proof of funds?

Answer (score 1):

I'm US citizen and have traveled extensively to Shenghen over the last ten years, and only once (in Germany) was asked about the return tickets. I didn't have them with me in hand (only on computer), and was let in without showing them. The remaining dozen times nobody asked for anything.

This also depends on the country you're entering the Shenghen area. Netherlands and Germany, for example, are those who ask most questions (purpose of trip, where you stay, how long), while in Italy or Spain nobody has bothered asking anything, and sometime they even didn't stamp my passport.