# Landing questions at a USA airport

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

I am travelling to the USA next week. What questions does the Immigration officer ask when you arrive at the airport, and also: can they see that you once overstayed in Europe if you do not have an overstay stamp in your passport but just an exit stamp? My visa has already been approved.

Comment: I don't think asking about other-country overstays is a common question. If they do ask it, it may mean they know about your overstay, and are testing your honesty.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has similar answers as [UK Immigration officers arrivals interview questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49231/uk-immigration-officers-arrivals-interview-questions)

Comment: @PaulofOsawatomie you voted to close as **off topic** because **duplicate** of a question about a **totally different** country? Are you serious? Off topic because is a duplicate?

Comment: @motoDrizzt I voted as a duplicate. And yeah I am very serious. What is the material difference in questions asked visitors by immigration? Who said anything about off topic?

Comment: @PaulofOsawatomie no, you didn't vote as a duplicate, duplicate is the option at the top of the list. You voted as Off topic -> Other -> and wrote a reason stating that it's off topic 'cause it's a duplicate. It totally makes no sense at all.

Comment: @motoDrizzt He voted to close for the reason he said he voted to close. The sequence of menu choices he took in the site's user interface are not part of his reason.

Comment: @motoDrizzt  Sorry if it makes no sense to you when I explained my motivation clearly but then that's your problem not mine.

Comment: The fact that the answers are the same for different questions does not make the questions duplicates. What's the smallest denomination bank note issued by the Bank of England" : £5.00 and How much does coffee and a cake at restaurant X cost? : £5.00. Duplication comes from question content not the answer, here different countries might have different questions.

Comment: They usually won't have a way to know. Nevertheless, what questions asked depends on the mood of the immigration officer (and the day). Usually they let me in without questions asked, but once I was interrogated by an officer for about 10-15 minutes.

Answer (score 5):

The questions vary but there are several one which come up quite often:

- Where are you going?
- How long are you staying?
- Where do you work?

These are by far the most common, but they also regularly ask:

- Why are you going there?
- Do you know anyone at the destination?
- Who are you travelling with?

After starting with one of these questions, they usually follow up on your response. In my experience, if you volunteer more information than required, they usually ask more follow up question. Although a lot of follow up questions, come up naturally. If you respond that you are going to a conference, they can ask what type of conference or something like *who is the sponsor?*, *who is paying for you conference?* etc.

It is possible for them to ask about previous trips too but in my experience this almost never happens except if you have stamps from certain hot zones such as Afghanistan & North Korea, among others.

Comment: I've been asked when I was last visiting the US -- with no reason to think it was anything but completely routine.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably expect landing interview questions like:

- Where do you live?
- Where are you going?
- What do you plan to do there?
- Where are you staying?
- What do you do for a job?
- When do you plan to leave the US?

If the officer does not like one of your answers, they can ask you an unlimited number of additional questions.